# Ember computed property doesn't fire when bound to deeply nested property

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript

This [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vumeh/1/edit?html,js,output) isolates a problem I ran into in my code. I have a hierarchy of embedded models and a computed property (`data`) that is supposed to fire whenever a value at the very bottom of the chain changes (`symbol`). The example displays the property directly as well as the result of the computed property. A button changes the value on click. You'll see that it updates the property but the computed property doesn't fire. Why doesn't `selectedAllocation.positions.@each.instrument.symbol` work to trigger the computation when any `instrument.symbol` changes?

If the example seems contrived, it's only because I tried to abstract something that is more complex in reality, e.g. there is more than just one object in these arrays and `data` is necessary because another library expects a simple JS object in a particular format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that @each only works one level deep. You cannot use nested forms
>   like todos.@each.owner.name or todos.@each.owner.@each.name.

http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/

You'll need to create an alias to bring `symbol` up one level (Not a coffeescript guy, hopefully you can read through the hacking, the `positions` alias below is for kicks and giggles, makes no difference).

```
App.Position = Ember.Object.extend({
  instrumentSymbol: Em.computed.alias('instrument.symbol')
})

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  selectedAllocation: null
  positions: Em.computed.alias('selectedAllocation.positions'),

  data: (->
    @get("positions").map (position) ->
      symbol: position.get "instrumentSymbol"
  ).property "positions.@each.instrumentSymbol"
  ...
```

http://jsbin.com/bivoyako/1/edit

Comment: Thanks! Gotta love when the answer is staring you in the face in the docs. I could have sworn I tried an alias but maybe I didn't do it in the right place. I'll give this a try and report back.

Comment: I was right. I had tried the alias before. But what I didn't do was *access the alias* inside the computed property code. I was still `get`ting `instrument.symbol`. I didn't realize that mattered. I thought that computed properties fired whenever something in the property list fired, but it doesn't. It only fires if I use a getter for the listed property in the body. Is that expected?

Comment: Ember generally lazily loads properties, so in this case, since no one was ever accessing the property, it was probably never evaluating it, and never watching it in turn.  <- conjecture, but I'd bet that was the cause (even more interesting would be if hitting it once would be enough to prime it).

Comment: That's a good conjecture, but doesn't it "hit it once" when the app boots, since it's displaying the initial value (directly and indirectly) fine? I guess you mean the alias though?

Comment: Yeah, the alias itself probably stays uninitialized due to never being used.